# Plotting FREQZ (both amplitude and phase) in 1 graph only

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Plot using FREQZ(signal) gives 2 different graphs - the amplitude response and the phase response.

What I want to happen is both amplitude response and phase response be in one graph only since we're only required to have one in our GUI.

I searched for it and found something about DFILT. Unfortunately, I really cannot understand how it works.

Please help or at least give me a general idea or a sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two functions, `freqz` and `phasez`. Both of these functions will return a vector of their respective x and y values

```
[f,w] = freqz(someFilter,...);
[phi,w] = phasez(someFilter,...);
plotyy(w,abs(f),w,phi)
```

This will plot both the phase and frequency response on the same figure with different y axes since the units of the two are likely to be very different.

Comment: Whoa. That worked! I only need to put labels to distinguish which is which. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd like to bring this up again. It seems like it only works on FIR filters (Not sure either since I have no test values for FIR Filters). I'm receiving no plot values when using it in IIR filters. `[f,w] = freqz(handles.vectorA,handles.vectorB);
                    [phi,w] = phasez(handles.vectorA,handles.vectorB);
                    plotyy(w,abs(f),w,phi)`

Comment: how am i to know what your filter is from you just putting vectorA and vectorB?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y1vFbMnr Here's the whole code. My test values are: N=4, Fc=1kHz, Fs=30kHz, Rs=60, Rp=0.1, Filter=cheby1 lowpass. Expected plot (http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag2/paozaf/xpctd_zpsa01d8d8a.jpg), real plot (http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag2/paozaf/real_zps57800e09.png). They're returning both same values (http://pastebin.com/WbTmw1fD).

Comment: I am not going to be able to look at these for a little bit (blocked at work) but I will take a look when I get home later today